# What's the difference between a standard Windows Phone app and a Windows Phone Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

What's the difference between those two? And why should I choose one over the other?

Comment: Primarily opinion-based? I asked the difference between two things, which leads to a fact.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about Windows Phone 8.1 which gives the the choice between building a Universal App and a Silverlight App?

Universal Apps allow you to re-use the majority of your code if you then want to then develop a Windows Desktop app equivalent. It should really be your default choice if developing a new app from scratch in most cases.

The Silverlight option is to provide an easy upgrade option if you're porting a Windows Phone 8 app to Windows Phone 8.1 - it'll allow you to use 8.1 features without re-writing your existing WP8 code.

Comment: But why did Microsoft came up with this? What is the purpose of Silverlight in Windows Phone Development?